# Addition Table: Python3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, nested-loops

For the question below I done what I can shown in , but don't really know where to go from there. I just started working with end values and am probably going to destroy this small code farther.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIuJt.png]

---

```
# Inputs
range_start = int(input("Enter start value:"))
range_end = int(input("Enter end value:"))

# Calculations
for loop in range(range_start, range_end + 1):
answer = range_start + loop
print("{}|".format(loop), "{}".format(answer))
```

Comment: Please copy the code as text here, not in images.

Comment: alright got it, my bad

Comment: In order to receive more feedback, it would be in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for people to help you. What is your question here?

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: it's an assignment @RodrigoNey

Comment: Please also copy the question text as text here. (I hope you aren't doing that to avoid your teacher finding this question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I came up with. The main part of the script is that it uses `str.format` to allow for easier formatting with the numbers for the table. `print_overall` gets output strings from `output`. After printing the list of columns and the dashed line, `print_overall` prints row by row. I recommend checking out "6.1.3. Format String Syntax" in the docs for more info. about `str.format`.

```
def output(values = None, row_num = None):
    res = ""
    if not row_num:
        res += " " * 2
    else:
        res += row_num + "|"    
    for i in values:
        res += "{:5}".format(i) #{:5} allows for filler space when string length < 5
    return res

def print_overall(rnge):
    print(output(rnge))
    print(output(["-"*5]*len(rnge)))
    for row_num in rnge:
                #for every row number, make an list that maps values
                #where all the column numbers are added to the current row number
        lst = list(map(lambda col_num: row_num + col_num, rnge))
        print(output(lst, row_num = str(row_num)))


range_start = int(input("Enter start value:"))
range_end = int(input("Enter end value:"))

input_range = range(range_start, range_end+1) #+1 because range is exclusive at endpoint
print_overall(input_range)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need two loops.  I'm going to make a 2 dimensional matrix (just a list of lists), where `matrix[0][0]` is `0+0`.

```
mat = []
for i in range(0, end+1):
    mat.append([])
    for j in range(0, end+1):
        mat[i].append(i+j)
```

This isn't quite the output your assignment asks for, and I encourage you to go the last little bit on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little more compact:

```
matrix = [[i+j for i in range(start, end+1)] for j in range(start, end+1)]
```